# AJAX POST request not working with XMLHttpRequest in Laravel

Tags: laravel, xmlhttprequest

I'm using XMLHttpRequest to avoid using JQuery and I wanna make an Ajax request to delete an object but I keep getting redirected back and getting FOUND (302) HTTP errors.

This is my code:

```
   function deleteGuia(urlToSend) {
        var borra = confirm('¿Está seguro de borrar la guía?');
        if (!borra) {
            return;
        }
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
        req.open("POST", urlToSend, true);
        req.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrfToken);
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (req.readyState === 4) {
                if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
                    console.log(this.responseURL);
                }
                if (req.status != 200) {
                    var msg = JSON.parse(req.response);
                    alert(msg.error);
                } else {
                    alert('Exitoso');
                }
            }
        }
        var data = new FormData();
        var guia = "{{$guia ?? ''}}";
        var estado = "{{$tipo ?? ''}}";
        data.append("guia", guia);
        data.append("tipo", estado);
        req.send(data);
    }
      </script>
```

This one's the controller function:

```
public function eliminarGuia(Request $request) {
        $request->validate([
            'guia' => 'required|numeric',
            'tipo' => 'required'
        ]);
        $guia = (int)$request->input('guia');
        $tipo = $request->input('tipo');
        \Log::info('Guia' . $guia . ' Tipo: '. $tipo);
        if (strtoupper($tipo) === 'ENTREGA'){
            $borra_guia = Guia::where('guia', $guia)->where('estado', $tipo)->delete();
            $borra_ciclos = Device::where('guia_recepcion', $guia)->delete();
            if(!$borra_guia) {
                return response(400)->json(['error', 'La guía no se encontró.']);
            }
        } else if (strtoupper($tipo) === 'REVERSA') {
            $borra_guia = Guia::where('guia', $guia)->where('estado', $tipo)->delete();
            $devices = Device::where('guia_reversa', $guia)->get();
            if (!$borra_guia){
                return response(400)->json(['error', 'La guía no se encontró.']);
            }
            foreach($devices as $device)
            {
                if (!$device->fecha_recepcion) {
                    $device->delete();
                } else {
                    $device->guia_reversa = 0;
                    $device->fecha_reversa = null;
                    $device->save();
                }
            }
        } else {
            return response(400)->json(['error', 'La guía no se encontró.']);
        }
        return response(200);

    }
```

web.php

```
Route::post('borrar_guia', 'VistasController@eliminarGuia')->name('borrar_guia');
```

There's no redirection at all. Why might that be happening? I don't know what else to add. The controller should return a 200 code when it delets an existing object in the database but it's getting a 200 from the redirection.

Comment: It may be the validation failing and trying to redirect with errors. Are you sure your data is been validated correctly ?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking but it's just two variables: For example: guia as a numeric value: 1111111 and the second called "tipo" as a string: "entrega". I've checked and they are correct but some how they are not passing the validation and I don't know why.

Comment: I thought the key=value&key=value is for get requests, a post request data is held in the body

Comment: try using the Validator::make($request->all(), [ 'key' => 'required']);  and check if   $validator->fails()  and then if it fails you can return $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray() so you can check the error that the validation is giving you

Comment: Just changed it to a formdata (which is what I was using at the beginning)

Comment: So @Eli I tried and no params are reaching the controller.

Comment: Found a solution in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46112782/revisions but I'm still wondering what's wrong with FormData. Is it the encoding?